# Optaplanner vehicle max utilization

Tags: optaplanner

First i like opta planner a lot, its awesome! I have tried other routing engines also, but no ever is even near to the opta planner vehicle routing results.

I have currently adopted OptaPlanner 6.2.0.CR3 release and its even better in terms on vehicle routing than previous release, near by selection is awesome

However while generating routes i am seeing one pattern for which i need your guidance:-

1. Vehicles are not being utilized up to max capacity, even they have some stops near to them which they could have serviced with in time window. are assigned to other truck
2. Is the scores get impacted if two trucks are created, one with full capacity and other with one stop in comparison to two trucks, one with 90% filled and other with two stops in same area location
3. I am seeing pattern like above, what would any one suggest to me?

Is there a way, i can force algorithm to fill trucks until demands meets or time window constraint meets, not taking care of near by stops or any other constraint

It would be really helpful if any one can assist me.

Thanks
Swayam

Comment: For 2. sounds like we need nearby selection for subchain change moves too. That's not yet supported in 6.2 out of the box.

Comment: Sometimes it's more efficient to use more vehicles, even if less vehicles can handle it, [as demonstrated in this blog](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2013/08/06/FalseAssumptionsForVRP.html). If you really don't want that, check if your score function clearly marks less vehicles as more efficient and verify you don't have a "score trap" (see docs). But it's possible that for big problems, the move's simply aren't selected often enough (and nearby selection for subchain change move will make it get selected more)